# How to apply the same font to everything on the page?

Tags: css

Let's say that I want to specify Arial in the HTML header - and I want it to apply to everything.

Do I have to list each element type explicitly? Or can I set them all with a single statement?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `*` selector which applies to everything:

```
<style>
* {
    font-family: Arial;
}
</style>
```

Note that this may be overkill for your purposes - due to the nature of CSS, styles set on parent elements are generally inherited by child elements, and thus, it's usually enough to set a font style on the `body` element to apply to the entire page.

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. Since I am a CSS n00b, please tell me how to do that within HTML header tags & the answer is yours

Comment: Just wrap it in `<style>` and `</style>` tags (within the `head`). I edited the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: +1 again - and the answer - thanks! Sorry to be such a n00b. I think I'll go buy a book, or read a few tutorial sites :-)

Answer (score 4):

No, generally specifying it on `body` is enough. That’s what the C in CSS is for: cascading. That means elements inherit the properties of their parent element. So anything under `body` (which should be everything) will inherit the font automatically.

```
body { font: 12px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer

```
body {
   font-family: Arial;
}
```

and let it cascade down. This has the advantage of not stomping on explicit font selections further down the tree. If you want to stomp, use the `*` form in other answers

Comment: If you really want it to be arial no matter what, you can still do this and use !important, right?