# override font in template page

Tags: css, fonts, overriding, laravel-5

i'm trying to override the font in my website template

i've try this in my internal css

```
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face
    {
        font-family:avenir-black;
        src: url('{{ asset('fonts/AvenirLTStd-Black.woff') }}') format('woff');
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family:avenir-medium;
        src: url('{{ asset('fonts/AvenirLTStd-Medium.woff') }}') format('woff');
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family:avenir-light;
        src: url('{{ asset('fonts/AvenirLTStd-Light.woff') }}') format('woff');
    }
    .avenir-black
    {
        font-family:avenir-black;
    }
</style>
```

and this is how i'm using the class

```
<div class="home-text avenir-black">
            <h1 class="hs-line-14">
                WHERE TO STAY?
            </h1>
            <br><br>
            <h1 class="hs-line-15">
                Need somewhere to stay?
            </h1>
            <h1 class="hs-line-8">
                We have a list of possibilities!
            </h1>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <div class="local-scroll">
                <a class="scroll-nav local-scroll" href="#hotels">
                    <h1 class="hs-line-10">
                        See All Possibilities
                    </h1>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

but nothing happened.. i am using laravel 5.2 as my framework and i save the fonts file in public/fonts folder

Comment: You need to declare the font family for your elements in your css. Ex: `h1{font-family:'avenir-black'}

Comment: how if i want to make some css class that i can use everytime i need?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking but this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519266/how-to-apply-the-same-font-to-everything-on-the-page

Comment: Where did you get those `.woff` files from? You need a license to use that font on your website. When you buy a license the font foundry will give you a snippet of code to add to your site to make it all work, so it could be something to do with that.