# How to change the default font in vuetify app

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I'm trying to change the font from *Roboto* to *Poppins* in a Vuetify app. I'm using webfontloader to load the font. I've tried several ways for changing the font, but it either doesn't work at all or it doesn't change the font for all elements.

**webfontloader.js**

```
export async function loadFonts () {
  const webFontLoader = await import('webfontloader')

  webFontLoader.load({
    google: {
      families: ['Poppins:100,300,400,500,700,900&display=swap'],
    },
  })
}
```

**main.js**

```
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import { loadfonts } from './plugins/webfontloader'
import App from './App.vue'

loadFonts()

createApp(App)
  .use(vuetify)
  .mount('#app')
```

In App.vue I currently override the font-family like so, which changes the font for most part, but vuetify built-in classes like `text-h2` or `text-body-2` still use *Roboto*.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<style>
html {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif !important;
}
</style>
```

What is the correct way to change the font for the whole application?

### Edit

In the style section, I've also tried to apply the font to everything with the `*` selector according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3519275/6608142). Unfortunately this doesn't work.

If I select the relevant classes one by one, then it works. For example like so:

```
html {
  .text-h2 {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif !important;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this is not scaleable and it's very likely that I forget a class. I need a general way of changing the font.